# Как определить за максимум два сравнения существует ли треугольник со сторонами длиной a, b и с?

Tags: математика, геометрия, олимпиада

> Даны три числа: a, b, c. Как определить за максимум два сравнения
>   существует ли треугольник со сторонами длиной a, b и с?

В случае с `a+b>c, a+c>b, b+c>a, (a>0, b>0, c>0)` все ясно, но как сделать это за **2** сравнения?

ps вопрос не учебный, встретился при подготовке к [собесу](https://coremission.net/gamedev/voprosy-dlya-sobesedovaniya-unity3d-programmista/) :)

Comment: Дополнительные переменные использовать можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде бы никаких ограничений нет, думаю что можно

Comment: Отсортировать список переменных входит в число сравнений? Если 0<a<b<c, то достаточно проверить a+b>c

Comment: Не нужно ответ помещать в вопрос, если вам есть что добавить — напишите отдельным ответом, пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейNOP это был не ответ, а код с проверкой, да ладно уже

Comment: Ну вы можете его найти в истории правки вопроса и перенести его в ответ. В любом случае в вопросе ему не место

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a + b > c
abs(a - b) < c
```

Comment: А если ещё abs накрутить, может и в одно условие всё можно завернуть? Вообще, конечно, бредовое задание для собеседования.

Comment: @АндрейNOP вопросы общие, которые я нашел в нескольких источниках и везде +- одинаковые вопросы, что на ру, что на en форумах

Comment: @АндрейNOP Лехко. Формулу Герона помнишь? всего-то и проверить что подкоренное выражение неотрицательно - одно сравнение.

Comment: @Akina, конечно помню, итого `p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c) > 0`, где `p = (a + b + c) / 2`. Что в итоге можно упростить до чего-то вроде `(a + b + c) * (b + c - a) * (a + c - b) * (a + b - c) > 0`. Только не неотрицательно, а строго положительно, потому что для 0 получится не треугольник, а отрезок (типа 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Угу. Ну и первую скобку можно смело опустить - уж она-то в минус ну никаким боком...

Comment: @Akina, а что насчет отрицательных чисел? Типа -1, -1, -1?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ввод отрицательных - это ошибка ввода (некорректные исходные данные). Что вообще-то должно проверяться и блокироваться ещё до этапа расчёта.

Comment: У abs же внутри сравнение :(

Answer (score 3):

Вот еще вариант, из скалярного произведения векторов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вообще, все они в конечном итоге одно к другому сводятся...